# How to set time of progress bar according to my method work?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

**Scenario**: I want to implement the functionality on this method runTask() it should be appear for a specific time, it should take the time that browse button take to upload the xlv file in database.

This is my method when I want to show progress bar I call this method in a browse button method.

```
    //Start of prograssbar method call
    private void runTask() {

        final double wndwWidth = 300.0d;
        Label updateLabel = new Label("Running tasks...");
        updateLabel.setPrefWidth(wndwWidth);
        JFXProgressBar progress = new JFXProgressBar();
        progress.setPrefWidth(wndwWidth);

        VBox updatePane = new VBox();
        updatePane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        updatePane.setSpacing(5.0d);
        updatePane.getChildren().addAll(updateLabel, progress);

        Stage taskUpdateStage = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        taskUpdateStage.setScene(new Scene(updatePane));
        taskUpdateStage.show();

        Task longTask = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                int max = 100;
                for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        break;
                    }
                    updateProgress(i, max);
                    updateMessage("Task part " + String.valueOf(i) + " complete");

                    Thread.sleep(10);
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        longTask.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
                taskUpdateStage.hide();
            }
        });

        progress.progressProperty().bind(longTask.progressProperty());
        updateLabel.textProperty().bind(longTask.messageProperty());

        taskUpdateStage.show();
        new Thread(longTask).start();
    }

    **//end of prograssbar method**
```

Below is the browseButtonClicked method is to load the file and split it and send it to the database. Both these methods are in a same class.

```
    private long count;
    private CopyTask copyTask;
    **//start of browseButton**     
    @FXML
    private void browseButtonOnClicked() throws InterruptedException {

        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                new ExtensionFilter("Excel Files", "*.xlsm", "*.xlsx", "*.xlt", "*.xlv", "*.ods", "*.csv"));
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);

        count = selectedFile.length();

        /*
         * Im counting files length of selected files. and progress bar & indicator is showing
         */



        if (selectedFile.getAbsolutePath() != null) {
            filePathField.setText(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
//        System.out.println(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());

        Scanner input = null;
        try {
            input = new Scanner(new File(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()));
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        /**
         * Need To ask from the user whether he wants to remove his previous
         * data or not if users proceed further all of the data would lost
         */
        if (confirmMessage("It will erase all of your previous data\nDo you want to proceed further?")) {

            **//this method is for progressbar call method**
            runTask();

            /**
             * Here Need to execute a query which will erase all previous data.
             * The data of pats, allocated students and unallocated students
             * will be lost.
             */
            if (patListButton.isSelected()) {

                String deleteQuery = "TRUNCATE patsinformation;";
                dataBase.executeQuery(deleteQuery);
                listItems.clear();
                pats.clear();

                deleteQuery = "TRUNCATE studentsinformation;";
                dataBase.executeQuery(deleteQuery);
                deleteQuery = "TRUNCATE unallocatedstudents;";
                dataBase.executeQuery(deleteQuery);

                students.clear();

            } else if (studentListButton.isSelected()) {

                String deleteQuery = "TRUNCATE studentsinformation;";
                dataBase.executeQuery(deleteQuery);
                deleteQuery = "TRUNCATE unallocatedstudents;";
                dataBase.executeQuery(deleteQuery);

                students.clear();

            }

            while (input.hasNextLine()) {


                if (patListButton.isSelected()) {

                    /**
                     * Here the under given query will erase of previous data.
                     * Delete Everything from pats information table.
                     */
                    tokensPATInformation = input.nextLine().trim().split(",");
                    listItems.add(tokensPATInformation[1]);

                    pats.add(new PAT(tokensPATInformation[0], tokensPATInformation[1], tokensPATInformation[2], tokensPATInformation[3], tokensPATInformation[4], tokensPATInformation[5],
                            tokensPATInformation[6]));

                    String query = "INSERT INTO patsinformation values(" + '"' + tokensPATInformation[0] + '"'
                            + "," + '"' + tokensPATInformation[1] + '"' + "," + '"' + tokensPATInformation[2] + '"'
                            + "," + '"' + tokensPATInformation[3] + '"' + "," + '"' + tokensPATInformation[4] + '"'
                            + "," + '"' + tokensPATInformation[5] + '"' + "," + '"'
                            + tokensPATInformation[6] + '"' + ");";
                    dataBase.executeQuery(query);

                }

                if (studentListButton.isSelected()) {

                    String deleteQuery = "TRUNCATE studentsinformation;";
                    dataBase.executeQuery(deleteQuery);

                    deleteQuery = "TRUNCATE unallocatedstudents;";
                    dataBase.executeQuery(deleteQuery);

                    /**
                     * Here the under given query will erase of previous data.
                     * Delete Everything from students information and
                     * unallocated students table.
                     */
                    String result = input.nextLine();
                    tokensStudentInformation = result.trim().split(",");

                    /**
                     * getting the data of each year student seperately to get
                     * hnadle the data easily. And to avoid using of loops again
                     * and again to find the data of a single year student. It
                     * is done because if auto allocattion is allowed then the
                     * system may able to select different students.
                     */
                    if (tokensStudentInformation[3].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Year-1")) {
                        year1Students.add(result);
                    } else if (tokensStudentInformation[3].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("year-2")) {
                        year2Students.add(result);
                    } else if (tokensStudentInformation[3].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("year-3")) {
                        year3Students.add(result);
                    } else if (tokensStudentInformation[3].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("year-4")) {
                        year4Students.add(result);
                    }

                    students.add(new Student(tokensStudentInformation[0], tokensStudentInformation[1],
                            tokensStudentInformation[2], tokensStudentInformation[3], tokensStudentInformation[4],
                            tokensStudentInformation[5]));

                    String query = "INSERT INTO unallocatedstudents values(" + '"' + tokensStudentInformation[0] + '"'
                            + "," + '"' + tokensStudentInformation[1] + '"' + "," + '"' + tokensStudentInformation[2] + '"'
                            + "," + '"' + tokensStudentInformation[3] + '"' + "," + '"' + tokensStudentInformation[4] + '"'
                            + "," + '"' + tokensStudentInformation[5] + '"' + ");";
                    dataBase.executeQuery(query);
                }
                final TreeItem<AssignPAT.Student> root = new RecursiveTreeItem<AssignPAT.Student>(students, RecursiveTreeObject::getChildren);

                tableView.setRoot(root);
                tableView.setShowRoot(false);
                tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
                        SelectionMode.MULTIPLE
                );
                listView.setItems(listItems);

            }
        }
    }
```

**thank you! Looking Forward for positive response!**

Comment: What is the logic behind this? *"I'll just run some sample code demonstrating how to correctly execute long-running operations in JavaFX, then I'll block the application thread with a long-running operation anyway.*

Comment: I just show the JFXProgress bar when the file is uploading. I just wanna know the exact time slot that a file, xlv, or any task complete . I just want to show the progressbar when the task is running the prograss bar appearing correctly the issue is the calculation and period of time the progress bar should be appear.